# Why does the approximation for exponents $(a+b)^c \approx a^{c-bc} (a+1)^{cb}$ work?

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation, approximation

I was working with some code involving exponents in an environment where exponents can only be calculated if the base of the exponent is an integer. I needed a good fast way to approximate this without causing overflow issues. I accidentally stumbled upon an incredible approximation method and I'm not sure why it works.

Suppose you have an exponent in the form of $x^y$ where $x$ is not an integer and you want to approximate the value using only exponents which have integers for their base-values.

Break $x$ into two parts, an integer part, and an additive. For example $3.7\to 3 + 0.7$.

Therefor, $x\to(a+b)$ where $a$ is an integer part.

The approximation formula is:

$$(a+b)^c \approx a^{c-bc} (a+1)^{cb}$$

Or in my original form:

$$(a+b)^c \approx ((a+b)-b)^{c(1-b)} ((a+b)+(1-b))^{cb}$$

It's remarkably close to the right solution seemingly every time. Granted I've only been able to check about 100 cases, but I'm fascinated.

For example:

$$37.5^{28} ≈ 37^{14}\cdot38^{14}$$

And sure enough, if we divide both parts, the ratio is 1.002 which is very close.

Edit: Thanks to RayDansh pointing out in the comments, this is accurate IFF $a+b$ is big. In fact, the larger $a$ gets the more accurate this approximation seems to get.

Can anyone shed some light as to why this approximation method I've stumbled upon works?

Comment: Well, here's your intuition. The exponent terms you've discovered are such that whichever of $a$ and $a+1$ are closer to $a+b$, those will be weighted more than the other term. And both happen to be remarkably close to $a+b$. Hence your discovery.

Comment: What about $1.5^{100}≈1^{50}*2^{50}$? Quite inaccurate.

Comment: Just trying to show how the approximation loses accuracy as $x$ decreases and $y$ increases.

Comment: @RayDansh I think the point is that it improves for large $a$.

Comment: @RayDansh Right you are; I was only testing with large numbers. Seems to get 100% accurate as `a` approached infinity. How odd

Comment: Well, for large $a$ and small $b$ we have $(a+b)^c\approx a^c=a^{c-d}a^{d}\approx a^{c-d}(a+1)^{d}$

Comment: @Holo The point is that in the first estimate you went down and in the second estimate you went up, why did these roughly cancel out upon the choice $d=bc$? In other words, why is $\frac{(a+b)^c}{a^c} \approx \frac{(a+1)^{bc}}{a^{bc}}$?

Comment: @lan this is just for intuition, I did not work out the reason this works better than, for example, $d=c/2$(also didn't check if it really is better)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Write your approximation
$$a^{c-bc} \cdot (a+1)^{cb}=a^c\left(1+\frac 1a\right)^{bc}$$
and your approximation is $$\left(1+\frac 1a\right)^{b}\approx 1+\frac ba$$
Which is the first two terms of the binomial expansion.  It will be reasonably accurate when $\frac ba \ll 1$  The next term is $\frac {b(b-1)}{2a^2}$

Comment: Doesn't get clearer than this +1

Answer (score 7):

As a general rule, if you see a lot of products and exponents it may clear things up to take logs.  In your case,

$$(a+b)^c ≈ a^{c-bc} \cdot (a+1)^{cb}$$

becomes

$$c \log(a+b) \approx  c(1-b) \log(a) + cb \log(a+1)$$

or just

$$\log(a+b) \approx (1-b) \log(a) + b \log(a+1).$$

This is equivalent to doing a linear interpolation of $\log x$ between the points $a$ and $a+1$.  This will be pretty accurate when $a$ is large because $\log x$ will be close to linear between $a$ and $a+1$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is obvious.  If we expand both sides of the formula by the binomial theorem, we get for the first two: $(a+b)^c=a^c+cba^{c-1}+ ...$ for both forms of the equation.  Now, it is immediately apparent that this approximation will improve as a gets larger because the discarded terms become less significant.  That is, for larger a, $a^n>>a^{n-1}$.

Comment: Of course it improves, but why is it significantly better than just keeping $a^c$?

Comment: Look at the rest of the binomial expansion terms that are omitted above